# Link to a specific query with the Bigquery Web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I do many queries in bigquery that look something like:
select foo, bar, baz from [table_DATE] where ggg = VALUE order by time_field

I'd like to create a set of links where I can pre-fill in both DATE and VALUE and get the user to select run query.   Is there anyway I can construct a URL for this?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, currently. We'll take this as a feature request suggestion.

Comment: Is there a link for this feature request

Comment: This would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually available now

You can [`save`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/saving-sharing-queries#saving_queries) your queries and have them as

- Private (Visible only to you)
- Project (Project members can view and edit)
- Public (Anyone with the link can view, but not edit)

after that you can [`share`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/saving-sharing-queries#sharing_queries) them or just use for yourself as a shortcut